# problem with python list

Tags: python, list, text-files

Hi im trying to create a list adding to it via a for loop reading line by line from a txt file. Im getting a syntax error on the list but am unsure about how to fix the problem ???

```
import re
file = open("text.txt","r")
text = file.readlines()
file.close()

line_count=0

for line in text:
    User_Input_list[] += [] + line.split()
    line_count += 1
```

**the problem seems to be on the second last line with the declaration of the list**

Comment: "declaration"?  Python doesn't have declarations.  What do you think is going on in that line?  Please clarify your understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
input = []
line_count = 0
with open("text.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        input.extend(line.split())
        line_count += 1
```

Comment: or you could use `for line_count,line in enumerate(file,start=1):` as a way of rolling the counter in the loop definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not
`UserInputList += line.split()`?

Comment: This would create a nested list (which of course may or may not be what the OP wanted, the question is a bit unclear).

Answer (score 0):

If you want each line in the file to be a separate element in the list, here's a simpler way to do it:

```
import re
file = open("text.txt","r")
text = file.readlines()
file.close()

line_count=0
line_list = []
for line in text:
    line_list.append(line)
    line_count += 1
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
import re
file = open("text.txt","r")
text = file.readlines()
file.close()

line_list = []
[line_list.append(a_line) for a_line in text]
line_count = len(line_list)
```